# Find the number of restricted permutations

Tags: permutations

Find the number of permutations of ABCDEFGHI such that the patterns ABC, DEF, GHI do not occur.
I am getting $181434$.
$$(9!-9!/3!\cdot3)-3!$$

Comment: Such that none of them occur, or such that not all of them occur?  In other words, is ABCDEFIHG acceptable because not all of ABC, DEF, and GHI occur, or is it unacceptable because at least one of ABC, DEF, and GHI occurs?

Comment: @BrianTung  none of them.

Comment: The raw result is not very enlightning. You should explain your way of reasoning.

Comment: When you say "pattern," do you mean a not necessarily contiguous subsequence?

Comment: Your answer does not make sense.  The second term counts permutations in which $A$ comes before $B$ and $B$ comes before $C$ or $D$ comes before $E$ and $E$ becomes before $F$ or $G$ comes before $H$ and $H$ comes before $I$ while your last term counts permutations of the blocks $ABC$, $DEF$, and $GHI$.  Brian Tung has shown you how to count permutations in which none of those blocks occurs.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig The most appropriate approach is to assume the patterns as an entire unit and proceed. I did it that way, but the answer isn't at all close. But all I could do is to come up with the nonsense calculation in order to match one of the four given choices.

Comment: If you use the subsequence interpretation, you should get $210,000$, which is still much larger than the answer in the answer key.

Answer (score 2):

**Sketch of approach.** First find the number $N_{ABC}$ of combinations that contain ABC.  You can do this by treating ABC as a single "letter", along with the other actual letters D through I.  Note that $N_{DEF} = N_{GHI} = N_{ABC}$.

Now, if you add up $N_{ABC}+N_{DEF}+N_{GHI}$, you get an expression that is somewhat of an overcount of the number of disqualified permutations.  The reason is that a permutation such as GABCHIDEF is counted under both $N_{ABC}$ and $N_{DEF}$.  You must therefore use [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) to count them properly.  You need to determine $N_{ABC,DEF}$ (by treating ABC and DEF both as single letters), and also $N_{ABC,DEF,GHI}$ (by treating ABC, DEF, and GHI all as single letters).  Then the number of disqualified permutations is

$$
N_{ABC}+N_{DEF}+N_{GHI} - N_{ABC,DEF} - N_{ABC,GHI} - N_{DEF,GHI}
+N_{ABC,DEF,GHI}
$$

Finally, subtract from $9!$, the total number of permutations, to get the number of qualified permutations.

Comment: As if the group of patterns are contained in box? Yes, tried it. But could you please point outvthe exact number??? It'd be of great help

Comment: I think I get $348114$.

Comment: The answer provided is 169194

Comment: The closest was 181434.

Comment: Well, then there's a possibility that the question doesn't mean what I think it means, because my enumeration code just produced $348114$ permutations that I think qualify.